Bigfoots, stargates, and the BIble
Recently I was reading some of the writings of a Christian writer named Steve Quayle, and was wondering if what he teaches is supported by the Bible. From what I understand he teaches that the Nephiliim mentioned in Genesis 6 were fallen angels, and that their offspring were literal giants. Then, as time progressed, these giants somehow ended up becoming the modern day bigfoots. Along with their large size he also teaches that they can use 'stargates' to travel around, and that they can move objects with their voices. My question I suppose, is whether or not any of this is biblical.
(Here's the link to his website, he used to have another website called genesis6giants but I cant seem to find it. https://www.stevequayle.com/

"As time progressed, these giants somehow ended up becoming the modern day bigfoots". Since this would require that they somehow survived the Flood, it's trivial to show that this supposition is false.

Deuteronomy 3:11  "For only Og king of Bashan remained of the remnants of the giants; behold his bedstead was a bedstead of iron...nine cubits was the length thereof, and four cubits the breadth of it, after the cubit of  a man." This verse calls him a giant, and this passage certainly comes after the flood. The sons of Anak in Numbers 13:33 which says "And there we saw giants, the sons of Anak, which come of the giants..." Both of these verses speak of giants being in existence after the flood. How that happened however, is still debated.

Sure, but the problem isn't the claim that there were giants post-Flood. The trick would be to show that they're descended from the Nephiliim. To do that, you'd have to show either a) that either Noah or his wife or one of his sons' wives are descended from the Nephiliim, or b) such descendants survived the Flood (despite Scripture explicitly saying otherwise).

There actually were Nephilim post-flood, not just their descendants. The passage I cited from Numbers uses the word 'Giant' but this is  translation of the word Nephilim. Obviously your second explanation isn't true, because nobody but Noah and his family survived the flood, but I suppose your first explanation could be accurate. Seeing as how the Nephilim appeared after the flood however, means that they made it through somehow. So, yes there were giants after the flood. But, there were also Nephilim after the flood. The Bible is fairly clear, somehow the Nephilim existed after the flood.

You can read the totality of what is Biblical about the Nephilim in three verses -

The Nephilim were on the earth in those days—and also afterward—when the sons of God went to the daughters of humans and had children by them. They were the heroes of old, men of renown. (Genesis 6:4)

and

And they spread among the Israelites a bad report about the land they had explored. They said, “The land we explored devours those living in it. All the people we saw there are of great size. 33 We saw the Nephilim there (the descendants of Anak come from the Nephilim). We seemed like grasshoppers in our own eyes, and we looked the same to them.” (Numbers 13:32-33)

Some scholars also say that Ezekiel 32:27 is also a reference to the Nephilim, but this is not universally agreed.

But they do not lie with the fallen warriors of old,[a] who went down to the realm of the dead with their weapons of war—their swords placed under their heads and their shields[b] resting on their bones—though these warriors also had terrorized the land of the living.

Everything else about the Nephilim is non-biblical, interpretation or speculation.
The First Book of Enoch (a non-canon Jewish writing) describes the Nephilim as the offspring of the "sons of God" (who are described as fallen angels) and human women, which is not contradicted by the Genesis passage. It also describes them as giants. This is a widespread interpretation. Other interpreters see the Nephilim as the offspring of Seth (Adam's righteous son) who later rejected God ("fell").
The view that the Nephilim were the offspring of fallen angels is fairly mainstream, though not universally accepted (even among those who take Genesis as literal history). It fits pretty well with the Biblical account. However any statement that they survived and became "Bigfoot" is utter and complete speculation without biblical support.

One cultural thing that makes my head spin a bit is how it has come to be so widely believed that the Nephilim were otherworldly, and how they are termed "sons of God" (which only ever meant humans) despite being unscripturally hailed as "fallen angels", and yet some of the same readers try to find fault with the Scriptural observation that Lucifer was a son of the morning, the same description elsewhere applied to Jesus, to imply that the two were once brothers. It might be helpful to cite a source or two about where this belief about the interpretation of the "sons of God" is coming from.

I get that the Book of Enoch term "watchers" is commonly cited as the origin of the idea of fallen angels being some kind of extraterrestrial, and it is clear that some who had been called "sons of God" rebelled against God and that some angels fell. This is Scriptural. However, linguistically, the introduction of another term rendered in our language as "watchers" doesn't seem to be distinct from a shallow synonym. There is much that is being read into the term seemingly for novelty's sake. Maybe I should ask my own question about this, because it seems like a common interpolation.

There are elements of truth to it but it is fantasized to the point of absurdity.
Nephilim were giants. So were the Naphtuhim. There are several races of giants that are known to have existed. To my knowledge, they were all Hamites. Goliath of Gath was one of them. When we speak of giants, we are not talking about ridiculous 30-foot tall, physically impossible creatures as seen in some hoaxes that may have been designed to discredit the idea of giants altogether. Giants are real, but we are talking about human beings up to nine and a half or ten feet tall (about the height attributed to Goliath).
Speculation about "fallen angels" or otherworldly creatures interbreeding with humans is completely unscriptural. Humankind are frequently referred to in Scripture as the offspring of God. Hence saying that sons of God marrying daughters of men is a redundant figure of speech that does not refer to "otherworldly" beings. There is no Scripture anywhere that says some "other" kind of being joined with humans to produce giants or any other kind of being. Giants are simply large humans. By large in this context, of course I mean people probably 8 to 10 feet tall as described earlier.
For a very broad definition of "bigfoots", yes, it is literally true that giants would have big feet. But the cultural baggage behind that term has to go. "Bigfoot" per American folk legend doesn't really mean anything since there is no such creature.
God can move things with His voice, as can others who have the power of God:

For the brother of Jared said unto the mountain Zerin, Remove—and it was removed. And if he had not had faith it would not have moved; wherefore thou workest after men have faith. (Ether 12:30).

The Brother of Jared was likely one of the Naphtuhim, although it is not his lineage but his faith that was the determining factor in his ability to move objects by his speech. On the point of lineage though, Carlos de Siguenza y Gongorra insisted the ancient Aztec records affirmed that their predecessors were conclusively identified as the Naphtuhim (the records were later destroyed by the conquistadores). According to Josephus, the Naphtuhim or Nedim had disappeared from the Old World.
Jacob attests that by faith in Jesus Christ a man can speak and move objects by the power of the Creator:

Wherefore, we search the prophets, and we have many revelations and the spirit of prophecy; and having all these witnesses we obtain a hope, and our faith becometh unshaken, insomuch that we truly can command in the name of Jesus and the very trees obey us, or the mountains, or the waves of the sea. (Jacob 4:6)

Celestial beings can of course travel at superluminal speeds and can choose to appear to mortals or remain hidden.
No offense but Steve's Quayle's site looks more like a sales front than a source of reliable information. Discarding the sensationalism, there is truth behind some of the claims, but I would not take him as a reliable source of truth.
There are more than a few people who cherry-pick Scriptures, mingle them with hoaxes, and tell partial truths together with Hollywood sensationalism and folk legends to get a following. Why? Because it sells to a certain kind of mind.
My faith is, and always has been, that truth is far more interesting and is better than fiction.
Yes, giants are Biblical.
Yes, moving objects by speech is Biblical.
Yes, superluminal travel is Biblical.
But visits from aliens, 30 foot giants, Bigfoot and Stargate are not. Again my suspicion is that one of the reasons why these latter things exist is to tempt people to ridicule Scriptural truths by conflating them with things that are fantasized and exaggerated.
But a man moving a mountain by the power of the word of God? It actually happened, as did the global Flood of Noah's time, and so on.
The greatest miracle is truth, not fiction: The resurrection of Christ is real. This is a far more significant fact than one's physical stature or racial origin, the speed at which one can travel, invisibility, or even the power of God's word to displace objects.
All things are possible with God. My admonition is to leave fantasy where it belongs, gathering dust, and come and learn and live up to the whole truth. It is better.
